# SUM Every row as Total

Tags: sql-server-2005, sum

I was looking for before posting but I don´t find anything. I don´t know if is possible what I want.

I want the sum of  every column in the same row. For a better explanation, I attach a picture. I am using SQL Server 2005

Example:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you tried any **code**?

Comment: What I tried don´t works for me, so, only I´m asking if is possible to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your requirement suggests a lack in the design of your database. Maybe you should refactor it and create another table where you insert one row for every column and a foreign-key to the main-table. That will be much more efficient and makes it easier to maintain and to write queries.

However, you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT [TOTAL ROW] = Col1 + Col2 + Col3 + Col4 + .....,
       OtherColumns ...
FROM dbo.TableName
```

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion, about the design of my database. I wanted to know if that was possible